# How can I change the input format for dates in Google Docs' spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

The input string for dates in Google Docs's spreadsheet app seems to be set to en_US, which is quite unnatural to me.

How can I change the input format?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Under [File > Spreadsheet settings...](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=61596).

[image: File > Spreadsheet settings.] Updated: [image: Spreadsheet settings...]

Select the locale with the date format you want (for example US is `mm/dd/yyyy` and UK `is dd/mm/yyyy`).

[image: Spreadsheet Settings]

Updated:

[image: Locale nd Time zone]

Comment: That's a Calendar, not Google Docs setting.

Comment: Changed to show Docs instead of Calendar (same system for selection).

Comment: Is there any english speaking locale that uses `yyyy-mm-dd` international format?

Comment: Is there any english speaking locale that uses mostly the `yyyy-mm-dd` international format? [Looks like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) `Canada (English)` might do the trick, but it's a bit confusing as it also accept other standards.

Answer (score 8):

The answer from @Metalshark is great for updating existing documents, but I'd also like to point out that this can be set as a default.

Click the gear icon on the right from your main Google Drive dashboard and select **Settings**. If you don't have a language selected you can set it here. This should apply to all future documents.

[image: Google Drive language setting]

Comment: Thanks - good to know! 
(wonder why the GBs used was hidden :)