# Google Docs date in “dd/MM/yy” format

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any way to use date in format `dd/MM/yy`? The Google Docs support only `MM/dd/yy` and it cause us problems to use it (we can't sort the date column).

Comment: Wow this was hard to find! Some keywords: Google Calendar European date format for date/time columns.

Comment: Wondering exactly the same thing!! You should make below your answer.

Answer (score 31):

I guess you're talking about Google Spreadsheets.

You can do that if you go to *File* → *Spreadsheet settings...* and change the **Locale**:

[image: google spreadsheet settings]

Comment: Can I change the locale for all documents including new ones?

Comment: @romkyns Yes. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/45775/28950

Comment: Thanks, champion!! Who would have thought!?!? I went through date formatting and it still wasn't working. THIS is what fixed it...

Comment: Does only work when all sheets have the same date format...

Answer (score 3):

To change the date format to dd/mm/yy - go to your Google Apps gear wheel -> settings -> Language -> click the drop down box and select English (UK) - that gets you dd/mm/yyyy by default. Sorry if you are anything but British, but that seems the best way to do it as a user. I'm trying to do it for a whole domain to save users using different date formats and getting snarled up - not found how to do it yet!

There is a setting in Google Admin control panel -> Domain settings -> Language, which I've set to English (UK), but I've noticed one of my users is still coming up showing mm/dd/yyyy format. Meh.

Comment: How does your answer differ to that already given?

Comment: Does only work when all sheets have the same date format...