# How automatically convert data in Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have date information like this:`February 1, 2014`. I want to transform them into `2/1/2014` in Google spreadsheet. I have hundreds of dates so that I cannot transform them by hand. What should I do?

Comment: Which date notation is mentioned under `Format>Number` in your spreadsheet? If `MM/dd/yyyy` is present, then you must select Lawrence's answer. His solution is most straightforward in this case. My answer is only valid if you can only select from `dd/MM/yyyy` dates. Date notations are dependant upon locale settings: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13824/google-docs-date-in-format-dd-mm-yy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DATEVALUE` and formatting, from the Format menu option, result in the following date notation:

`February 1, 2014` ==> `01/02/2014`

You want, as stated in you question, this:

`February 1, 2014` ==> `02/01/2014`

What you need to do is the following:

### Conversion

1. create a new column on the left or right side of the column you want to alter.
2. add the following formula at the start position, you want the formula to begin:
   `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A)=TRUE,"",DATEVALUE(TEXT(A2:A, "MM/dd/yyyy"))))`
   [image]

   The `TEXT` formula will convert the string into the desired format: `month/day/year`.  The `DATEVALUE` formula will convert the string into a date. The `ISBLANK` formula, in combination with the `IF` statement, will only show a result, when the cell/range contains a value. The `ARRAYFORMULA` will take on the ranges of the `ISBLANK` and `TEXT` formulas and show the result of that range.
3. After you did the above-mentioned, you can copy/paste the values or keep using the newly created column

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[How automatically convert data in Google spreadsheet?](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdFBUc3hEd0F5ME9lX2pKS2pOOGxjbFE&usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 0):

Select all the cells, click on Format in the menubar
Then click on Number, then the date selection in the menu is the format you want.

Comment: The format, wanted by the OP, doesn't exist in the format options.

Comment: It was in mine...came up as MM/DD/YYYY in that Number menu - see screenshot - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1RhPrxJp7gybzFhaEFiRG5odFE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1):

Google spreadsheets have a function for this, DATEVALUE(). See this [question/answer](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/OMutgSWuXME)

Comment: The link doesn't describe in detail how to handle this situation. Plus the formula itself will give a faulty date format.