# Google Docs date in yyyy/mm/dd format (year first)

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, date, google-sheets-dates

My question is similar to [Google Docs date in “dd/MM/yy” format](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13824/google-docs-date-in-dd-mm-yy-format) and [How can I change the input format for dates in Google Docs' spreadsheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5482/how-can-i-change-the-input-format-for-dates-in-google-docs-spreadsheet)

BUT

unlike those answers, I'm trying to get the format with years first, which is non-ambiguous, more tech friendly and can be sorted alphabetically. I'm not aware of any locale that would put years first ?

Also, is it possible to automatically convert dates that would be typed with dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd ? (assuming my colleagues locale is indeed dd/mm/yyyy and NOT mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 2):

I did not realize there was a "Format > Number > More formats > More date n Time formats" where I could specify the exact format I want, since the default date format is not what I am looking for.

It also handles auto-formatting of further inputs

Comment: but with only that it don't recognize "13/07/2021" as a valid date

Comment: the rest depends on the language you have configured on the google sheet I believe