# How to edit dates in Google Sheets as ISO 8601?

Tags: google-sheets, date

I know how to make Google Sheets display dates in ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD). Now, how do I make them not only display, but edit in the same format?

See the edit line below:

[image: Date not editable as YYYY-MM-DD]

Moreover, if that is linked to [a locale in use](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5482/how-can-i-change-the-input-format-for-dates-in-google-docs-spreadsheet), which one would have a dollar sign as a default currency sign in addition to having ISO dates?

Answer (score 2):

## Partial answer

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country,
the following locales use YMD date format:

Afghanistan, Albania, Bangladesh, Cambodia, Canada, China, People's Republic of, Denmark, Germany, Hong Kong, Hungary, Iran, Japan, Kenya, Korea, Latvia, Lithuania, Macau, Mongolia, Myanmar, Namibia, Nepal, Norway, Singapore, Slovenia, South Africa, Sri Lanka, Sweden, Taiwan,Republic of China, United Kingdom, United States of America

## Notes

I didn't find a simple table that combines the date format and currency symbol but find the following that could help

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_symbol

## Other interesting findings

### Spefications / open source projects

Google participates in the below projects, so is very likely that Google Sheets use them

- http://cldr.unicode.org/

> The Unicode CLDR provides key building blocks for software to support
> the world's languages, with the largest and most extensive standard
> repository of locale data available. This data is used by a wide
> spectrum of companies for their software internationalization and
> localization, adapting software to the conventions of different
> languages for such common software tasks

- http://site.icu-project.org/

> ICU is a mature, widely used set of C/C++ and Java libraries providing
> Unicode and Globalization support for software applications. ICU is
> widely portable and gives applications the same results on all
> platforms and between C/C++ and Java software.

### Tools

- http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp

> This demo illustrates the International Components for Unicode
> localization data. The data covers two hundred five different
> languages, further divided into four hundred eighty-eight regions and
> variants. For each language, data such as days of the week, months,
> and their abbreviations are defined.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. That page lists only China, Lithuania, South Africa, Sweden, Taiwan, and Cambodia certainly using needed format. E.g. Japan uses `yyyy年mm月dd日` not `YYYY-MM-DD`