# GoogleSheet's Output of IMPORTXML Function Changes Format of Imported ISO Date-Time Text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, importxml

I have a GoogleSheet that's been working fine using the `IMPORTXML` function, until recently.

It seems that when the function imports XML data that are in ISO date and time format that it changes the format.

For example:  importing "2021-12-20T00:00:00" becomes "12/20/2021 0:00:00"

That is:

> YYYY-MM-DD**T**HH:MM:SS

becomes

> MM/DD/YYYY H:MM:SS

Since the worksheet has been using the `MATCH` function, the GoogleSheets imported value will not match the XML code's value.

How can this be resolved so that GoogleSheets imports and processes the data in "YYYY-MM-DD**T**HH:MM:SS" format as it did before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that Google Sheets is identifying as a date-time value and displaying it using the default date-time format for the spreadsheet region that your spreadsheet is using.

You could use ISDATE, ISTEXT or other ways to verify if the value is date / text and set your formula to use the appropriate value to do the match, i.e. you could use `TEXT(value, "YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")` to convert the date into a value having the formatting that your formula requires.

Related

- [How to edit dates in Google Sheets as ISO 8601?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/90327/88163)
- [What date formats does Google Sheets recognize?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/112318/88163)
- [Convert columns of ISO 8601 strings to dates in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/142818/88163)

Comment: Do you when the app, GoogleSheets, adopted this process of applying the user's regional default date-time format rather than the imported XML data's format?  The formulas had worked fine until recently.

Comment: In general, this was the default behavior but I don't know about the specific case of IMPORTXML... Are you sure that nothing have changed in the way that the XML files are being generated?

Comment: I'm almost certain that the XML format hasn't changed since the source XML data are from a US government website that's regularly queried from around the world.  I was curious when the changes took place since it may require my changing old worksheet queries to comply with this default format in effect.

Comment: Better to look if they have a place to notify changes, you might be surprised.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be recent changes in Google Sheets's [announced release changes](https://support.google.com/a/table/7314896?hl=en).  Thanks though.